# Should TypeScript interfaces have all object properties?

Tags: typescript

I have an API request that returns JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "results": [...],
    "info": {
        "seed": "99fd970f02554a4a",
        "results": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "version": "1.4"
    }
}
```

I'm only going to use the `results` data, so should my interface define the types of all `info` properties? Also, the `results' objects have properties that I'm not going to use. Should I define their types as well??

Comment: short answer, no

Comment: You only need to declare the properties you care about; it's generally okay if objects have more properties at runtime than the compiler knows about.   I'm almost positive this has been asked/answered before but I haven't found the right dupe target yet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [ask], espacially the part about what's on-topic here. This is very much a question with opinion-based answers.

Comment: Yeah there are various duplicate questions but they all have different opinion answers.